# ModX перенос сайта на php 7.x

Tags: modx, php7, php7.2

Всем доброго врмемени суток, возникла следующая проблема: сайт находился под управлением CMS ModX 2.3.1-pl. Я обновил CMS до 2.6.0 поэтапно (2.3.1 -> 2.4.0 -> 2.5.0 -> 2.6.0). Далее попытался изменить версию php до 5.6 и все работало норм. Далее, так как ModX с версии 2.5.0 начал поддержку php 7+ решил изменить на php 7.2 и вот проблема возникла именно здесь. Сайт перестал быть доступным. Как я понимаю доступным он перестал быть так как на версии php 7.х связь бд происходит иным образом. Поэтому приходится держать сайт на 5.6

Пожалуйста подскажите, как можно ModX обновить до php 7.2 версии. Что нужно изменить и в каких файлах?

Серч по нету не дал ответов...

Comment: Также пробовал сменить версию php на 7.2 и запустить обнову МодХ 2.6.0 -> 2.6.5 , site.ru/setup и в процессе установки вылитал error о том, что нет возможности подключиться к БД

Comment: Скорее всего проблема в каком-нибудь модуле. Отключите все модули/плагины и попробуйте.